# Traverse between activities in stack

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose I have activity instances A1, B1, A2, B2, C1 of activities A, B, C in stack. How can I traverse to Activity instance B1 from C1?

Let us generalize there will be 'n' number of activities between B1 and C1.

I don't want to create a new instance of B from C1.

Comment: Can you please explain ?

Comment: Use `ViewPager` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: @WaqasRaja I asked how to traverse between activities. Not traverse within activity using tabs. So answer is not ViewPager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a very bad architecture for Android. If you create multiple instances on an `Activity`, there is no way to specifically address them, for example: "Go back to the first instance of `ActivityB`". Android isn't designed like this.

You should avoid creating multiple instances of an `Activity`. It is beter to use the same instance and just create the "illusion" of multiple instances by swapping out the underlying data and maybe adding a state transition on the display so that it looks like you are starting another `Activity`.

Another possible solution would be to use a lot of `startActivityForResult()` and return information to the calling `Axctivity` about what to do next.

For more details see (even though these questions are specifically about using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, the problem is still basically the same):

- [Managing Android Activity stack: bring specific activity instance to front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008176/managing-android-activity-stack-bring-specific-activity-instance-to-front/17022316#17022316)
- [Multiple activity instances and FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949898/multiple-activity-instances-and-flag-activity-reorder-to-front/13382280#13382280)
- [Bring an activity to front using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964188/bring-an-activity-to-front-using-flag-activity-reorder-to-front/13383025#13383025)

Comment: 'It is beter to use the same instance and just create the "illusion" of multiple instances by swapping out the underlying data' - How can I use same instance of activity ? Can you explain? Thanks.

Comment: In order for me to help you, you need to explain why you are creating multiple instances of the same `Activity`. Give an example of the navigation in your app. Don't do this in a comment. Just edit your original post and add more details at the end.

Comment: I was just curious about traversing in stack. So I cannot provide navigation details in the app. Let me think a scenario and get back.

Comment: You should just rearchitect your application so that you do not open multiple instances of an `Activity`. Instead of opening a new instance of an `Activity`, go back to the the existing instance and give it new data to show. You can rearrange the stack of activities, but if you have multiple instances of the same `Activity` in the stack, this no longer works, because you cannot tell Android to return to (or to bring to the front) a **specific instance of a given `Activity`**.

Comment: I got the point now. There was a difficulty in understanding  **It is beter to use the same instance and just create the "illusion" of multiple instances by swapping out the underlying data**. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use Flags with Intent.

official Docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

pass the flag along with Intent

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

also you can paas multiple FLags in a single Intent according to your need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work. It will clear the task back to B2, not B1. OP has multiple instances of each `Activity` in the stack, and he wants to be able to go back to a specific one.