# Navigate & finish multiple instances of same activity on button click

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragmentactivity

This one is weird. I'm implementing breadcrumb navigation on a older app and I'm not at the point where it's ready to refactor the views. Unfortunately every new navigation opens a new activity and sometimes the new instances of the same activity. So my breadcrumb navigations basically look like this:

`Activity A > Activity B > Activity C > Activity C > Activity C > Activity C > Activity D`

So if I'm on `Activity C` and I need to go back to `Activity B` I can just set the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` for the intent and navigate back no problem. But if I need to navigation from the 4 instance of `Activity C` to the 2nd instance of `Activity C` I'm not able to use any intent flags to make that happen. My app is already making use of the back button so I cannot override that to utilize here. Does anyone have any ideas as to navigation among the multiple instance of Activity C?

Fortunately all these app do inherit from the same parent app which extends `FragmentActivity` if that is helpful.

Comment: Why are you not using Fragments though?

Comment: However if you must use Activities you can try looking up Activity Launch Modes. There are many and it's hard to explain here for me

Comment: @gtxtreme I'm not at the point the refactoring the app where I can turn the activities into fragments yet. Obviously in that case I can just pop the backstack however many times I need to. This app was created in 2014 and not updated since then.

Comment: I still don't understand in what case can a single activity be instantiated not one but 4 times

Comment: @gtxtreme This is very easy to do in Android, you can always call `startActivity()` and create a new instance of an `Activity`, even if the class you use is the same as the one making the call.

Comment: @gtxtreme It isn't possible to solve this problem using launch modes or `Intent` flags. See my analysis and discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39104837/769265

Answer (score 0):

To go back one item in your breadcrumb you don't have to use the BACK button, you can just call `finish()`, which will finish the current `Activity` and go back to the previous one in the stack.

To go back to a specific `Activity`, you can use `startActivity()` with flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, as you have already indicated in your question.

Anything else is not possible. See my answer to a related question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39104837/769265